# Need to use SQL to select Team Name and league name for teams that start with B

Tags: sql

```
select teamname
from league
where teamid in
 (select leaugename from Leagues
  where teamname like 'B%');
```

The error I get shows that there is more than one row returned
To clarify the team name is in table1, league name is in table2. They both have teamid in their tables

Comment: How can a teamid have the same value as a leaugename?

Comment: I'm doubting this query is throwing that error.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it.

Comment: Are "league" and "leagues" the same table?

Comment: team name and league name are in different tables

Comment: Make it easy - and possible - to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I think you need the below

```
  select table1.teamname,table2.leaguename
   from table1,table2
   where table1.team_id=table2.team_id
   and table1.teamname like 'B%';
```